# Find the distance between two lines given in parametric form (should be easy).

Tags: linear-algebra

**I am struggling with this problem in my math book, I cannot seem to get the calculation right even after MANY attempts. I have solved the question with other solutions but this one should also work. Any help would be much appreciated.**

So the problem is:

Find the distance between the two lines $L_1 = (1,1,3) = t(1, -2, -3)$ and the $L_2 = (6,5,0) = t(-3, 0, 1)$

Now we want to find the distance of some point $P$ on $L_1$ and some point $Q$ in $L_2$

$P = 1+t, 1-2t, 3-3t$
$Q = 6-3s, 5, s$

$\vec{PQ} = 5-3s-t, 4+2t, s-3 + 3t$

We know that $\vec{PQ}$ should be orthogonal to the lines $L_1, L_2$ hence:

$\vec{PQ} \cdot (1,-2,-3) = 0$ and $\vec{PQ} \cdot (-3,0,1) = 0$

This gives me the equation system:
$6s+14t = 6$
$6t+10s =18$

with the roots $s = \frac{27}{13},   t = \frac{-6}{13}$

By using these values in our $\vec{PQ}$ formula we get the $\vec{PQ}$ orthogonal to our lines:

$\vec{PQ} = 5-3(\frac{27}{13})-(\frac{-6}{13}), 4+2(\frac{-6}{13}), (\frac{27}{13})-3 + 3(\frac{-6}{13}) = \frac{-10}{13}, \frac{40}{13}, \frac{-30}{13}$

Now we find the length of the vector by using the $\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + c^2}$ formula and we get the result:

**$10\sqrt{\frac{2}{13}}$**

**The correct answer should be:**

**$\frac{20}{\sqrt{26}}$**

**What on earth did I do wrong?**

Thank you kindly for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. :) $$ 10 \sqrt{\frac{2}{13}} = 10 \sqrt{\frac{4}{26}} = 10 \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{26}} = \frac{20}{\sqrt{26}}.$$

Comment: Thank you!! Now I know that I was not far off at least!

Comment: Your comment worries me a little. You weren't off at all! Your answer and what you said the answer should be are the same number, just written differently.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I meant :) just another way to write the answer.