# distance between 2 lines in 3d

Tags: calculus, vectors

> Calculate the distance between the lines
>   $$L_1:x=4+2t,y=3+2t,z=3+6t$$
>   $$L_2: x=-2+3s ,y=3+4s ,z=5+9s$$

I tried subtraction $L_1$ from $L_2$ then multiplying the resting vector by the $t$'s and $s$'s original values and trying to find value for $t$ to or $s,$ but I found $t=\frac{19}{12} s$ and I don't know how to keep solving this.

Comment: is there a typo in the last equation $$z=5=9s$$?

Comment: what do you think is a reasonable definition of "the distance between two lines"?

Comment: You can take a look at the link and follow the directions to find the distance between two lines in vector forms. [Distance between two non parallel lines](http://planetmath.org/distanceofnonparallellines)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes its a typo it should be z=5+9s

Comment: A few very similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210848/finding-the-shortest-distance-between-two-lines, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310599/find-the-shortest-distance-between-two-lines-in-3d, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813497/find-the-distance-between-two-lines-given-in-parametric-form-should-be-easy, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188423/find-the-distance-between-two-lines, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709200/distance-between-two-skew-lines, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554820

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between the lines

$L_1:x=4+2t,y=3+2t,z=3+6t$ and $L_2: x=-2+3s ,y=3+4s ,z=5+9s$ is

$d=2 \sqrt{10}$

Indeed consider the function which gives the distance between a generic point of the first line and a generic point of the second line

$f(t,s)=\sqrt{(2 t-4 s)^2+(-3 s+2 t+6)^2+(-9 s+6 t-2)^2}$

and set to zero the partial derivatives $\partial f_t=0,\partial f_s=0$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 4 (2 t-4 s)+4 (-3 s+2 t+6)+12 (-9 s+6 t-2)=0 \\
 -8 (2 t-4 s)-6 (-3 s+2 t+6)+18 (-9 s+6 t-2)=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 17 s-11 t=0 \\
 53 s-34 t=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.$

which has one solution

$t= 0,\;s=0$

we have

$f(0,0)=2 \sqrt{10}$

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

A general solution is :
 take a point on $l_1 :A=(4+2t,3+2t,3+6t)$
take a point on $L_2: B=(-2+3s ,3+4s ,9s)$

find vector $\overline{AB}=B-A=\\(-2+3s ,3+4s ,9s)-(4+2t,3+2t,3+6t)$

then solve the system of equation $$\begin{cases}\overline{AB}.V_{l_1}=0\\\overline{AB}.V_{l_2}=0\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}\overline{AB}.(2,2,6)=0\\\overline{AB}.(3,4,9)=0\end{cases}$$ you will have two unknown and two linear equation ,here . $|\overline{AB}|$ is the minimum distance between two lines.

Comment: I have a typo line is z=5+6t and thats where my problem is I have a system of equation that equals 0 each si finish with t=39/10 s and i don't know how to continue from there.

Comment: If you find $t,s $ you find the length of $AB$ ,finished

Answer (score 2):

$ \hat a = 4\hat i + 3\hat j+3\hat k$

$ \hat b = -2\hat i + 3\hat j+5\hat k$

$\hat t =2\hat i + 2\hat j+6\hat k$

$\hat s = 3\hat i + 4\hat j+9\hat k$

$L1:  \hat a+t\hat t$

$L2:  \hat b+s\hat s$

So the distance $$d = \dfrac{\left|(\hat a - \hat b).(\hat t \times \hat s)\right|}{|\hat t \times \hat s|}$$

$\hat t \times \hat s = -6\hat i + 2\hat k$

$ \hat a - \hat b =  6\hat i - 2\hat k$

$\left|(\hat a - \hat b).(\hat t \times \hat s)\right| = 40$

$|\hat t \times \hat s| = \sqrt{40}$

Thus the distance $= \frac{40}{\sqrt{40}}$

$d = \sqrt{40} = 2\sqrt{10}$